# CLI Tool for Machine Stats

Tags: central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

Are there good CLI utilities to see things like CPU, RAM, and Network Traffic over time?

I know CPU can be looked at via a command like `top` but curious if there is any way to collect historical trends automagically. I basically want Datadog for a personal project but am trying to avoid paying for it (already did a free trial)

Comment: There are dozens of programs that can do this.  But if you want history, you don't want a cli, you want a service.  Typically you can't get much history or good graphs from a cli, although there are a few.  Software recommendations may be off topic here.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. There is [softwarerecs.se] for that.

Comment: What OS/s are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of zabbix? Might be what you are looking for. It's not a cli tool but a complete monitoring solution open source.

atop tracks historical metrics and is command line based.

It's packaged in Debian/Ubuntu and Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way for Linux (because you mention `top`) is to use `sar` from `sysstat` package. It can collect and display information about the CPU usage, network usage, RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

There's `iftop` for network, and `htop` is an alternative to `top`. If you want history, graphing etc, [munin](https://munin-monitoring.org/) is free and robust.